# How to delete all whitespace up to the first non-whitespace character?

Tags: whitespace, deletion

I'm looking for an emacs function that will delete all whitespace from the cursor position (including newlines) until the first non-whitespace character.

For example, if my cursor is positioned at the end of the first line:

```
main(arg1,
     arg2)
```

The delete function would result in:

```
main(arg1,arg2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might find the [`hungry-delete`](https://github.com/nflath/hungry-delete) package useful. I personally bind <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> to delete whitespace after point, and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete whitespace before point like so

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <backspace>") 'hungry-delete-backward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <deletechar>") 'hungry-delete-forward)
```

update: as of 12.2018 function definitions changed hence:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <backspace>") 'c-hungry-delete-backward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <deletechar>") 'c-hungry-delete-forward)
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this quite often:

```el
(defun join-line* ()
  "Join this line with the next line deleting extra white space."
  (interactive)
  (join-line t))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") #'join-line*) ;; just key binding I use…
```

Comment: I think it would be nice to note that this is equivalent to vanilla `C-u M-^`.

Comment: Note also that `join-line` (aka `delete-indentation`) often leaves one space character after point.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point)
                 (+ (save-excursion (skip-chars-forward " \n"))
                    (point))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`C-k` `M-\`

> `C-k` - Kill rest of line or one or more lines `(kill-line)`.
>
> `M-\` - Delete spaces and tabs around point `(delete-horizontal-space)`.